# Download File from Web

Tags: php, file, download, cloud

I have cloud with main directory uploads and when I try to download file I will get error "no file".

My directorys structure:

```
uploads
    /some_file.mp3
```

My code:

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "uploads";
    $files = scandir($target_dir);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        echo "<a href='$file' download>$file</a>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: whats the path from which you are executing the script and what is the path to the uploads directory? the snippet provided suggests that this script is being run in the same directory as the uploads. Is that correct?

Comment: You really have not given us much information here. All I can suggest is that you dont have a directory called `uploads` below your DocumentRoot directory, assuming that is where this code is being run!

Comment: I have in my ftp directory uploads where I have 2 files (.mp3 files) and script is in parent folder

Comment: I finally fix this error.. Thanks for help guys :)...

Comment: ftp directory is generally not accessable to web user.

Comment: PS: I changed echo "<a href='$file' download>$file</a>"; to  echo "<a href='$target_dir/$file' download>$file</a>";

Comment: Add it as an answer Marty and mark it as the correct answer, so it does not remain an unanswered question. Just a suggestion....

Comment: -Gavin Simopson Sorry but I dont know how mark it as correct ansswer. :D